# Why is it bad if items knows about container? Composite pattern (2 objects has references to each other) php

Tags: php

They say its not a good idea when tho objects has circular references. Lets see a composite example:

```
class Book
{
    private $title;

    public function __construct($title)
    {
         $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }
}

class Shelf
{
    private $books = [];

    public function addBook (Book $book)
    {
         $this->books[] = $book;
    }
}

$shelf = new Shelf();
$sehlf->add (new Book('a'));
$sehlf->add (new Book('b'));
$sehlf->add (new Book('c'));
```

so far so good. For some reason, `Book` must know about `Shelf`, so I rewrite:

```
class Book
{
    private $title;
    private $shelf;

    public function __construct($title, $shelf)
    {
         $this->shelf = $shelf;
         $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }
}

class Shelf
{
    private $books = [];

    public function addBook (Book $book)
    {
         $this->books[] = $book;
    }
}

$shelf = new Shelf();
$sehlf->add (new Book('a', $shelf));
$sehlf->add (new Book('b', $shelf));
$sehlf->add (new Book('c', $shelf));
```

and they say its bad.

Comment: If they say it's bad, they should explain why (Who are "they" BTW?)

Comment: "('a', $shelf)" the second parameter??

Comment: https://derickrethans.nl/circular-references.html 
this might help you

Comment: If "they say it's bad" where "it" is the fact that the book knows about the shelf, you might want to reconsider the assertion that "for some reason, `Book` must know about `Shelf`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with circular references which can be [found here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11856/whats-wrong-with-circular-references) but I must accept the above is not a very problematic example -- as it is clear that shelf must be created first before book.

One of the most common problems for example is that it may be 'impossible' to use `print_r` on the instance of `Book` above assuming the variables were public -- will lead to a memory exhaustion.

There a couple of ways to resolve circular reference issues, one of the most common which includes using [Setter injection](http://misko.hevery.com/2009/02/19/constructor-injection-vs-setter-injection/). e.g.

```
public function setShelf(Shelf $shelf)
{
    $this->shelf = $shelf;
}
```

Another issue particular with PHP is that it can have issues resolving circular dependencies. See [this for example](https://alexatnet.com/articles/optimize-php-memory-usage-eliminate-circular-references).

```
class Node {
    public $parentNode;
    public $childNodes = array();
    function Node() {
        $this->nodeValue = str_repeat('0123456789', 128);
    }
    function destroy()
    {
        $this->parentNode = null;
        $this->childNodes = array();
    }
}
function createRelationship() {
    $parent = new Node();
    $child = new Node();
    $parent->childNodes[] = $child;
    $child->parentNode = $parent;
    $parent->destroy();
}
```

PHP will end up allocating about 35MB of memory for no good reason. To resolve this, we may use a destructor so the garbage collector knows how to take care of the object once we're done with it.

```
function destroy()
{
    $this->parentNode = null;
    $this->childNodes = array();
}
```